# Install Unity gui

Tags: gui, mate-desktop, unity

How to install Unity GUI on Linux Mate without installing any other apps just the GUI so i can switch between it and Mate Gui.

I have tried this command but not worked:
`sudo apt-get install unity --no-install-recommends`

Comment: "Did not work" isn't very helpful. Include specifics on how it didn't work.

Comment: There is no change and there is no option for unity in login screen

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends tu-desktop
```

Comment: How did you determine that `tu-desktop` was the package that you needed to install? Don't just give a one-line answer; instead, describe how you arrived at the answer you are giving, and why it is correct. Doing so can make the answer useful even for people facing a situation where the specifics are different. As it stands, this answer can *only possibly* be useful for someone wanting to install specifically Unity on specifically Linux Mate; it can't be generalized.

Comment: I am new to Linux so i cannot describe what i made, i only searched more on google